# What JS syntax is used for this function parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What kind of parameter is this? `{ children }: { children: JSX.Element }`

This is the function declaration

```
function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  let location = useLocation();

  if (!auth.user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

I know that the function takes JSX component, but I still don't know which syntax the parameter uses.

Comment: Destructuring before the colon: TypeScript (or Flow) typing afterward.

Comment: That's not plain JavaScript syntax.

Comment: After the colon is an anonymous interface... think `interface ComponentProps { children: JSX.Element }`. The arg is then destructured... think `function RequireAuth(props: ComponentProps) { const children = props.children; ...`

Comment: I think it is the combination of Typescript and the latest Destructuring ES6 syntax.